# Spark writing to Cassandra with TTL based on column for Dataframe APi

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, ttl

Do we have an option to write to cassandra with TTL value based on a  timestamp column.
I saw that in RDD we have option to write with varying ttl based on column.Is same available for Dataframe api.

I have a Dataframe as below:

```
stime          Name
2019-12-24     abc  
2019-12-30     xyz
```

Usually Cassandra purge/delete rows based on loaded time(if TTL is 60,data will be deleted after 60 seconds of loading)
I want to delete records based on stime column.If my TTL is 7 days,it should delete only abc row even though I loaded two rows together.

Comment: I Suppose this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51134344/spark-writing-to-cassandra-with-varying-ttl

Comment: yes, that's the correct answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark writing to Cassandra with varying TTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51134344/spark-writing-to-cassandra-with-varying-ttl)